# Server (jsp) cannot send the data to MYSQL db due to inrecognizable internal errors aren't showing up in stackTrace

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, controller, database-table

I have created a web project that need to register user data in database table that can be used further.

registration.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function validateform(theForm) {
          var First_Name = theForm.First_Name;
          var Last_Name = theForm.Last_Name;
          var UserName = theForm.UserName;
          var phoneNo = theForm.phoneNo;
          var password = theForm.password;
          var reenter_password = theForm.reenter_password;
          var email = theForm.email;
          var gender = theForm.gender;
          var title = theForm.title;
          var day = theForm.dobday;
          var month = theForm.dobmonth;
          var year = theForm.dobyear;
          var atposition = email.value.indexOf("@");
          var dotposition = email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

          if (First_Name.value == "") {
            alert("Name can't be empty");
            First_Name.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (!First_Name.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
            alert("name contains invalid Characters!");
            First_Name.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (Last_Name.value == "") {
            alert("Name can't be empty");
            Last_Name.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (!Last_Name.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
            alert("name contains invalid Characters!");
            Last_Name.focus();
            return false;
          }

          /* user name validation */
          if (UserName.value == "") {
            alert("user Name can't be empty");
            UserName.focus();
            return false;
          }

          /* email validation */
          if (email.value == "") {
            alert("please enter your email");
            email.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.value.length) {
            alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:" + atposition + "\n dotposition:" + dotposition);
            email.focus();
            return false;
          }

          /* password validation */
          if (password.value == "") {
            alert("password can't be empty");
            password.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (password.value.length < 6) {
            alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
            password.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (reenter_password.value == "") {
            alert("please re-enter the password");
            reenter_password.focus();
            return false;
          }
          if (!password.value.match(reenter_password.value)) {
            alert("password must be same!");
            return false;
          }

          if (!gender[0].checked && !gender[1].checked) {
            alert("please select your gender");
            gender.focus();
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body id="html">
<center>
<br><br>
<section class="registration_form" >
<form name="registration"  method="post" action="registerUser.jsp" 
onsubmit="return validateform(this);">
<table id="tab1" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="60%" height="320%">
<td width="10%"></td><td><h1>Register here</h1></td>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td><label for="First Name">First Name</label>
        <input type="First Name" id="usernametxtbox"   name="First_Name" placeholder="enter First Name" >
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td><label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="Last Name" id="usernametxtbox" name="Last_Name" placeholder="enter Last Name" >
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td>
        <label for="User Name">User Name</label>
        <input type="User Name" id="txtbox" name="UserName" placeholder="enter User Name" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td>
        <td><label for="usermail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="txtbox" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" ></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtbox" name="password" placeholder="password" ></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td><label for="reenter_password">re-enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtbox" name="reenter_password" placeholder="Re-enter password"></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><tr height="10%"><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%"></td><td><label>Date of Birth:</label>
        <select name=birthday>
    <option> - Month - </option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select name="DOBDay">
    <option> - Day - </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="DOBYear">
    <option> - Year - </option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="196\6">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>

</select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><label>Gender:</label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked > Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td width="20%"></td><td><input type="submit" value="register" id="butn">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>  
    </table>
    </form>
</section>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

After submitted goes to `registerUser.jsp`

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<html>
    <body>
        <%
        String firstname=request.getParameter("First_Name");
        String lastname=request.getParameter("Last_Name");
        String username=request.getParameter("UserName");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        String month=request.getParameter("birthday");
        String day=request.getParameter("DOBday");
        String year=request.getParameter("DOBYear");
        String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
        String DOB=day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false";
            Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "admin", "admin");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                String QueryString = "insert into user_details(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USERNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,DOB,GENDER) values( '"+firstname+"',' " +
                        lastname+"', '"+username+"', '"+email+"', '"+password+"',' "+DOB+","+gender+");";
                statement.executeUpdate(QueryString);
                        %> 
                        User data inserted successfully
            <%      }
                        catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
                        finally{
                            statement.close();
                            connection.close();
                        }
            %>
    </body>
```

Every thing seems to be fine with variable names,checked if incorrect.  Included MYSql connector. Server works perfect.

I doubt in unidentified datatype mismatch in db or any other server-page error, as it isn't coming up in stacktrace, it's hard to find the flaw.

[image: Stacktrace Image]

*Please help out on this !*

I have table structure in MYSQL
[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had made a mistake in the SQL query

```
        String QueryString = "insert into user_details"+
           "(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USERNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,DOB,GENDER) values( '"+
           firstname+"',' " + lastname+"', '"+
           username+"', '"+email+"', '"+password+"','"+DOB+"','"+gender+"');";
```

if still not work then change this following code

check this code if work this work for me:

```
   Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demoDb";
    String login = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, login,password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection = null;
        System.out.println("drivernot found");
        System.out.println("SQLException:" + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
    }
```

Comment: **This is perfect !** the problem was with the driver path The same query i placed executed in workbench

Comment: Everything goes fine but i got a brand new problem, date field(DOBdate) from registration.jsp is sending Null value even through i give something to  it ! [https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=83F3A5EDD4E85B35!29162&authkey=!ALSxzuyigo3PEMA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG]